# TF diff entire set of files at once rather than one at a time

Tags: tfs, diff

When I run `tf diff`, either recursively or against a shelveset, it goes through file-by-file and runs `tf diff <myItemSpec>`.  I have my diff config set to compare files using windiff.exe which can handle a list of files, so running a new instance of windiff for every file is really annoying.

I remember being able to run windiff against an entire set of files at once years ago, but when I was working on that project, we were using two different versioning systems (originally our project was in TFS and we transitioned back to a proprietary versioning system, one that I'm certain had this functionality), so maybe TFS never could do this.

`tf folderdiff` seems like it should be the answer, but it doesn't appear that you can set the program it runs, nor can you specify a shelveset.  It just runs some TF GUI which then allows you to run your configured diff program on a single file at a time.

Am I remembering wrong and TF never could do this?  Is there there a hack/script that can do what I want it to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explaining tf diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158752/explaining-tf-diff)

Answer (score 0):

As here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166188/616827,

> tf diff $/Foo /version:C14317~C14318 /recursive /format:unified >
>   foo.diff

- `$/Foo` specifies the entire repo (not one file at a time)
- `/Version` to compare one changeset against the previous
- `/format` is optional